# How can I treat powdery mildew

Tags: diseases, grape-vine, mildew

I have a grape vine in my garden and each summer it starts off fine but then Powdery mildew seems to kick in as the summer progresses. Is there a way I can treat it?

Comment: What constraints are you under, treatment-wise? https://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7494.html

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean?

Comment: Some fungicidal treatments don't fit some people's interpretation of organic gardening, which they consider themselves to be engaged in. If we know that, we can attempt to provide answers that suit, and if we know it does not apply, we can provide answers without considering that. Or you can write your own answer (that's fine on these sites, take the [tour]) after perusing the linked page and/or others if you like, since you know your own preferences best, and I don't really have any personal homegrown secrets, so I just went looking for reputable information about powdery mildew and grapes.

Comment: Ah right, I've no problem using fungicidal treatments, I'm just an amateur gardener so was looking for some advice on whether there was something out there that would be successful

Answer (score 0):

I had powdery mildew on my bonsai and i used a fungicide i found on amazon but using baking soda also works quite well

Comment: Thanks for that. Did you use it in a spray with water?